# Assigning a unique ID for several rows based on certain values in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, gaps-and-islands

I have a CTE that returns something similar to what you see below:

```
Date   | ID | Category
--------------------
1/1/18 | 1  | Delivery
1/2/18 | 2  | Return
1/4/18 | 3  | Delivery 
1/5/18 | 4  | Middle
1/6/18 | 5  | Return
1/7/18 | 6  | Delivery
```

I am looking to add a unique and incrementing ID that starts with category = 'Delivery' and ends/resets after category = 'Return'.

For example...

```
Date   | ID | Category | New ID
-------------------------------
1/1/18 | 1  | Delivery |  1
1/2/18 | 2  | Return   |  1
1/4/18 | 3  | Delivery |  2
1/5/18 | 4  | Middle   |  2
1/6/18 | 5  | Return   |  2
1/7/18 | 6  | Delivery |  3
...
```

Most of my experience is with MySQL, so I could do this pretty easily with a stored procedure, but having a hard time figuring it out with postgres.

Note, this is all defined by CTE and is held in-query - I do not have an actual underlying table to UPDATE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use progressive `sum()` to calculate the number of instances of the `Delivery` category:

```
with my_data(date, id, category) as (
values
    ('1/1/18', 1, 'Delivery'),
    ('1/2/18', 2, 'Return'),
    ('1/4/18', 3, 'Delivery'),
    ('1/5/18', 4, 'Middle'),
    ('1/6/18', 5, 'Return'),
    ('1/7/18', 6, 'Delivery')
)

select *, sum((category = 'Delivery')::int) over (order by id) as new_id
from my_data

  date  | id | category | new_id 
--------+----+----------+--------
 1/1/18 |  1 | Delivery |      1
 1/2/18 |  2 | Return   |      1
 1/4/18 |  3 | Delivery |      2
 1/5/18 |  4 | Middle   |      2
 1/6/18 |  5 | Return   |      2
 1/7/18 |  6 | Delivery |      3
(6 rows)
```